# Laravel - Generating PDF after a Javascript has Loaded

Tags: javascript, laravel, pdf, laravel-5

I've recently come to appreciate a barcode generator called: http://lindell.me/JsBarcode/ - but the problem is, I need to include these barcodes in a generated pdf for print, and unfortunately, no matter what I try at the moment, I cannot get the barcode to be generated in the pdf.

At the moment I use: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to generate my PDFs, and while it loads images just fine, I am unsure if it is even possible for it to get my javascript to execute and then proceed to create the pdf from that.

If it's not possible, does anyone here have any suggestions as to what I should do?

At the moment my barcode images are using the following format to be generated: `data:image/png;base64,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`

### Update

This is from my controller, which calls for the PDF:

```
  public function downloadPDF(Shipment $shipment){
            $shipment_details = $shipment->shipment_details;


      $pdf = PDF::loadView('shipments.pdf', compact('shipment','shipment_details'));
     return $pdf->stream('shipment'.$shipment->url_string.'.pdf');
        }
```

and this is how the images are created using the JsBarcode scripts provided:

```
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="/dist/JsBarcode.all.js"></script>

    <script>
        Number.prototype.zeroPadding = function(){
            var ret = "" + this.valueOf();
            return ret.length == 1 ? "0" + ret : ret;
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

and in the main body:

```
<img id="barcode3"/>
<script>JsBarcode("#barcode3", "{{$shipment->pro_number}}", {
    format:"CODE39",
    displayValue:true,
    fontSize:20
});</script>
```

Now, I know the script works because I have used it on other pages and the barcode generates just fine, so I'm not sure where to locate the issue here.

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to call for the images and create the PDF?

Comment: I've included some of it above, if you need anything else just let me know :)

Comment: Might I ask how you delay between the image being rendered and calling the PDF? That was my first thought about your issue. If the PDF creation is called immediately there will not be any images for it to pick up to render.

Comment: At the moment I’m not, which was suggested on a forum post somewhere else. The main issue is I’m not sure how to delay it using this specific pdf creator or laravel. Did you have any suggestions? I’m always open to switching pdf creators, I just want the thing to work haha. And you’re likely right, I can see that if it’s immediately created, it wouldn’t have any time to pull up the image of the barcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check if the issue is related to rendering the images first is to delay the PDF call using setTimeout. If this works then one could consider keeping it as is or exploring other approaches such as a callback or promise.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var element = document.getElementById("WHOLE_DOCUMENT");
  JsBarcode(element, "Hi!");
},2000) //2000 = 2 seconds
```